# Magento2.1.7 extension installation error cronjob has not been configured yet

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento2

I am new to magento & I was installing an extension into my magento version 2.1.7 but the system readiness check shows the following error currently megento is present in my system with windows 8 operating system.

[Error shown while installing extension in magento2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81I0v.png)

[Error shown while installing extension in magento2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhp6C.png)

I have tried the below given solutions but no any solution is worked with it my magento directory also & from my system32 also.

```
php ls -al <your Magento install dir>/var/.setup_cronjob_status
```

It is showing the following response.

```
Could not open input file:ls
```

I also tried the below code

```
php crontab -u magento2.1 -l
```

&

```
php crontab -u Admin -l
```

where **magento2.1** is the **user name** of my Magento & **Admin** is my **system name**.
Both the code given an error as follows

```
Could not open input file:crontab
```

I am running this magento with Php **version 7.0.2** & **Xampp version 7.0.20-0-VC14**
Whether it is an error of not having cron in my system or something else?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to run the cron files of Magento by run the cron file separately.

Just simply go to the root directory of your Magento open command prompt there & run the below commands

> php bin/magento cron:run
>
> php update/cron.php
>
> php bin/magento setup:cron:run

Answer (score 2):

I installed Magento 2.1 in Windows 10 and work with these commands:

```
php bin/magento cron:run
php update/cron.php
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```